# Java and Hibernate throws unable to locate on a Transient attribute error. Why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

Hi I have similar question before and sometimes downvoted. But I really don't get it. i have base

```
@MappedSuperClass
public AbstractIdentity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Access(PROPERTY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    protected Long id;

}
```

Above class is extended by another class, which is extended by another class and so on...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBill extends AbstractClass{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RATE_ID")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TaxRate taxRate;

}
```

Finally there is again this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Invoice" + "." + "findAll", query = "FROM Invoice o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Invoice" + "."+"findById", query = "FROM Invoice o WHERE o.id = :id")})
@Audit(of = {"number"})
public class Invoice extends AbstractBill {

    @Formula("(SELECT\n" +
        "  (invc.AMOUNT + ( invc.AMOUNT * ISNULL(tx.RATE,0) ))\n" +
        "FROM INVOICE invc\n" +
        "  left join TAX_RATE tx on invc.RATE_ID = tx.ORIGINAL_RATE_ID WHERE invc.ID = ID)")
    @Getter
    @javax.persistence.Transient
    private Double taxAmount;
}
```

now when i access the attribute taxAmount from primeface to sort a column

```
<p:column styleClass="amountColumn" sortBy="#{item.taxAmount}">

...
</p:column
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [taxAmount] on this ManagedType [com.abcd.model.AbstractIdentity]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [taxAmount] on this ManagedType [com.abcd.model.AbstractIdentity]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.grc.abcd.web.model.SpecSearchLazyEntityDataModel.findEntities(SpecSearchLazyEntityDataModel.java:35)
    at com.grc.abcd.web.model.LazyEntityDataModel.load(LazyEntityDataModel.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:841)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.encode(SortFeature.java:99)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:692)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.faces.support.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:87)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:206)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.abcd.web.filter.abcdWebAppFilter.doFilter(abcdWebAppFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

If i put transient keyword from java, i get the same error. If i put @Transient from spring.data. The query gets executed at the start of the app which defeats the purpose.
I really don't know what to do here. I would like to sort the primeface datatable with a calculated derived value with Hibernate. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If I remember properly, Hibernate's `@Formula` is executed when the entitiy is instantiated. So is [`@PostLoad`](https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/11/17/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate-formula-annotation/) a possible alternative? If you're using `@PostLoad`, your *taxAmount* may be a standard `javax.persistence.Transient`

Comment: So @PostLoad on @Formula? so write a separate method on it and derive it through a normal method? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Al1.. i tried `@PostLoad` method 
`@PostLoad`
    public void  onLoad() {
        this.taxAmount =  new BigDecimal(geAmount() + (getAmount() * (getTaxRate() != null ? getTaxRate().getRate() : 0))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
    }
same issue. unable to locate attribute.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding: I assumed `@PostLoad` and `@Formula` are exclusive: you need to chose one: `@Formula` is hibernate specific whereas `@PostLoad` is standard JPA. But your comment shows that it is rather a matter of getter / setter (so pure Spring point?) rather than JPA stuff

Comment: Not sure if I get your point. use spring '@Transient' and assign the value to 'this.taxAmount' in '@PostLoad' method? It tried this but same thing.

Comment: If you use `@PostLoad`, you'll remove the `@Formula` and use `javax.persistence.Transient`. But anyway, it seems that it was not the root cause

Comment: Even if I put `javax.persistence.Transient` on getter. it throws the same error. Im really running out of ideas.